# jQuery AJAX - branching on result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have my first AJAX call with jQuery setup and working well. The final change I need to make is to check the result from the PHP page that is called for any database errors and display an error if required.

Here's my current Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#storeManager").change(function(){
            var storeManager = $("#storeManager").val();
            $.post('editProject.php', { type: 'storeManager', storeManager: storeManager, id: '1E1DDA14-D2C6-4FC8-BA5F-DBCCC7ABAF7F' }, function(data) {

                if (data.error) {
                    $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("danger");
                    $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                    $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("danger").html(data.text);
                } else { 
                    $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("success");
                    $("#storeManagerRow").removeClass("danger");
                    $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data.text);
                }

            }).fail(function (xhr) {
                // no data available in this context
                $("#storeManagerRow").addClass("danger");
                $("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-danger");
                //display AJAX error details
                $("#ajaxAlert").html(xhr.responseText);
            });
         });    
    });
</script>
```

I have the editProject.php page echo out a json encoded array like the following:

```
{"error":"true","text":"Error: No Project ID Found (Missing Parameter)"}
```

for errors and the following for a successful result:

```
{"error":"false","text":"Database Updated Successfully"}
```

At the moment is is never branching for the if (data.error) branch it's always branching to the else one, and it's not showing the text value either. If I change:

```
$("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data.text);
```

to:

```
$("#ajaxAlert").addClass("alert alert-success").html(data);
```

it does insert the following into the ajaxAlert div:

```
{"error":"true","text":"Error: Edit Record Error Unknown error (8003)"}
```

I'm new to jQuery and AJAX and working things out as I go - I feel like I'm very close but can't work out why it's not branching for the error and why it's not displaying the text value for either an error or successful result from the editProject.php script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following 2 things,

1. Parse the JSON response, `data = JSON.parse(data);`
2. Replace `if (data.error)` to if `(data.error == "true")`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the value of `data.error`... it should be a boolean value... not a string

so instead of assigning `'true'` in PHP assign the boolean value `true`

Answer (score 0):

Your `data.error` property contains a non-null non-empty string, which will always evaluate to true.

Instead use:

```
if (data.error === 'true') {
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, change your JSON to contain a boolean literal instead of a string:

```
 {"error":true,"text":"Error: No Project ID Found (Missing Parameter)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON has a string literal `"error": "false"` (which is a truthy value) instead of a boolean literal `"error": false` (which would be falsy).